# Post form-data on Axios (React)

Tags: reactjs, forms, api, axios

I've got the following component in React:

```
    const login = async (username, password) => {
    const response = await axios.post('/auth/jwt/login', {
        username,
        password
    });
    const {accessToken, user} = response.data;

    setSession(accessToken);

    dispatch({
        type: 'LOGIN',
        payload: {
            user,
        },
    });
};
```

Now, the problem is my API is expecting a form, whereas this request is sending a json on the body, thus I'm getting a 422 error (unprocessable entity).

I've tried creating a FormData() object but no luck so far:

```
    const formData = new FormData();

    const login = async () => {
    const response = await axios.post('/auth/jwt/login', {
        username: formData.username,
        password: formData.password
    });
    const {accessToken, user} = response.data;

    setSession(accessToken);

    dispatch({
        type: 'LOGIN',
        payload: {
            user,
        },
    });
};
```

Can anyone please help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Specifically you want to POST the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of as a JSON-encoded body.  According to [the documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/urlencoded), in the browser you would use `URLSearchParams` for this.  For example:

```
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('username', username);
params.append('password', password);
const response = await axios.post('/auth/jwt/login', params);
```

(That same documentation provides other options as well, to include 3rd party libraries or to POST from NodeJS.  The above is specific to in-browser code with no 3rd party libraries.)

Answer (score 1):

The previous solution didn't work for me. This did:

```
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('username', username)
    form.append('password', password)
    const response = await axios.post('/auth/jwt/login', form,
        { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } }
    );
```

In fact I could just do this:

```
    const login = async (username, password) => {
    const response = await axios.post('/auth/jwt/login', {
        username,
        password
        },
        { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } }
    );
    const {accessToken, user} = response.data;

    setSession(accessToken);

    dispatch({
        type: 'LOGIN',
        payload: {
            user,
        },
    });
};
```